# How to create radiobuttons from more than one column and make one active at a time

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii-components

I have two columns 'ReviewedDate' and 'Approved' . Now, I need to create 4 radiobuttons in the search form where each column will have two radiobuttons.('ReviewedDate' has 'Reviewed' and 'Not Reviewed' radiobuttons) and ('Approved' will have 'Approved' and 'Rejected' radiobuttons). Suppose if I click on any of this radiobuttons, the other three buttons should be inactive. Suppose I click on Approved, only approved radiobutton should be on and the rest three button should be off.
   How can I do this.

Comment: This is more javascript question then PHP.

Comment: @sskoko Sorry, I'm new to this. I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Give the same name for all 4 radiobuttons

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Reviewed"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Not Reviewed"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Approved"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Rejected"> And place in to two column

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your logic is correct. Let's say the document is "Reviewed", it can be furthermore "Approved" or "Rejected", if I get it correctly. On the other hand, the column "ReviewedDate" is supposed to contain a date. I would suggest a column state and a column change state date, or something...

Any ways, your problem is a html and javascript problem. Du make a radiobutton inactive you have to set the property "disabled". If you just want to uncheck all other radiobuttons once you click one, you simply have to give all of them the same name. Than your browser does the job.

Cheers,
Toni